# PagerSlidingTabStrip floating indicator

Tags: pagerslidingtabstrip

Is there and option to make indicator float under the selected tab ? I discribed the problem here : https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip/issues/67 becouse I am using forked lib as it alows me to setup custom views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple, simply wrap the PagerSlidingTabSTrip in a ViewGroup, and add some paddings, eg.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@color/pst_bg_color">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/psts"
        style="@style/BaseTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:background="@color/pst_bg_color"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:pstsTextAllCaps="false"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="@dimen/pst_indicator_height"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="@bool/main_pst_should_expand"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/pst_indicator_color"
        app:pstsDividerColor="@color/pst_divider_color"
        app:pstsUnderlineHeight="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```